# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; Unknown error

Tags: curl, jenkins

I have shell script to run from Jenkins. First step generates token. But when executed from Jenkins, it gives connection error

Jenkins here is Linux server

**Command**:

```
curl -w -X POST $URL -H Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded -H Content-Length:1045 -H Authorization:OAuth2 --data '{"grant_type":"password", "username":"User","password":"pwd"}' --write-out token
```

**Error**:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; Unknown error
>
> 100    88    0     0    0    88      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:01 --:--:--     0
>
> 100    88    0     0    0    88      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:02 --:--:--     0
>
> 100    88    0     0    0    88      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:02 --:--:--     0
>
> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Answer (score 1):

You failed to provide a value with `-w`.

This means that `-X` is taken that value instead of being a switch in its own right.

That means that `POST` is not taken as the value to the `-X` switch, so it is taken as the URL instead.

Remove `-w` or pass it a value.

Comment: once i remove -w, we are getting the below error: curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: @MeenaKumari — That's a different problem … which suggests the `$URL` variable is wrong and the server it is pointing to doesn't exist.

Comment: It is taking the url correctly, but still gives this error. Any suggestions please?